# Remove browser's scrollbar when popup is opened (html and CSS only)

Tags: html, css

The webpage I made is still scrollable when the modal is opened. I am trying to disable the scrollbar while the modal is open.

html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modalBack">
<div class="betaModal">
        <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></span></a>
        <h4>Tell Me Something</h4>
        <label>Your Email:</label> <input type="Email" name="Email" placeholder="example@mail.com"><br>
        <label>Subject:</label> <input type="text" name="title" ><br>
        <label>Message:</label> <input type="message-text" name="Message" placeholder="Write You Message Here ..."><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
<a href="#" class="bodyClose"></a>
    </div>
```

The button that toggles the modal:

```
<a href="#myModal"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light betaModelBtn">Contact Me</button></a>
```

CSS:

```css
.modalBack {
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 padding-top: 10%;
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}


.modalBack:target{
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
 position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no HTML-CSS solution at the moment.

When browsers will implement the `:has` selector, perhaps it can be done

```
body:has(> .modalBack:target) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

at the moment I would do so:

```
<a href="#myModal" onclick="document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light betaModelBtn">Contact Me</button></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also added the onclick to the modal closing elements with the value "visible" and it works great.

Comment: I suggest null or 'initial' to restore the default behaviour